# Fourier shift theorem for cyclic permutation

Tags: permutations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $h : \Bbb R^{d} \to \Bbb R$. I am quite confused how to apply the Fourier shift theorem to $h(Px)$ where $P\in M^{d\times d}$ is a cyclic permutation acting on $x$.

$$\mathcal{F}(h(Px))(k)=?$$

I guess some phase factors should pop out, but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for an invertible linear map $P$ the Fourier transform obeys:
$$ \widehat { h \circ P} = |\det P|^{-1} \hat h \circ (P^T)^{-1} .$$
When $P$ is a permutation matrix (not just a cyclic permutation) $\det P$ is always $\pm 1$ and $P^T = P^{-1}$, so this just reduces to $$\widehat { (h \circ P )}(\xi) =  \hat h (P \xi).$$

Comment: Thank you, my confusion came from the fact that I would expect that cyclic translation would result in Fourier  space into a phase factor. So from your answer I deduce there is no such an interpretation.

Comment: A phase factor would result from a translation, not from a linear transformation.

Comment: Looking further I found this; look at the shift theorem section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem   Is this reconciling with your answer?

Comment: That has to do with discrete periodic signals, i.e. $h : \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$. The shift theorem says that when you translate such a signal (essentially a cyclic permutation because of periodicity of the signal) you introduce a phase factor into the Fourier transform. But you have stated that your function $h$ is a function on Euclidean space, and your permutation matrix is permuting the coordinates of the input. Unless you mean something else entirely, in which case you should edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! the difference is now clear.